# How to backend-upload a video to Facebook, but with scheduled publish

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a php console script which uploads a video file to my Facebook Page. This works fine (code below). However when this finishes, the video is immediately available publicly. I would like to publish the video at a certain datetime.
I couldn't find the proper documentation for this. Is it available anywhere?
Alternatively, if I could upload the video available only to me, and then "turn it public", that would suit me also.

```
<?php
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '{APPID}',
    'app_secret' => '{APPSECRET}',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
]);
$accessToken = '{PERMANENTTOKEN}';



try {
    $videoTitle = 'FOO';
    $videoDescription = 'BAR';
    $data = [
      'title' => $videoTitle,
      'description' => $videoDescription,
    ];
    $basePath = '/path/to/';
    $fileEntry='file.mp4';
  $response = $fb->uploadVideo('{PAGEID}', $basePath.$fileEntry, $data, $accessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exception\ResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exception\SDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

echo 'Video ID: ' . $response['video_id'];  //this is now publicly available. how can i make it publish at a later date?
```

Comment: I have not checked if there is a documentation for scheduled post/publish for fb-graph-api. But as its CLI code, as an alternate case, you could use cronjob to upload it at desired time too, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `scheduled_publish_time` with the `published` parameter might work.

```php
$videoTitle = 'FOO';
$videoDescription = 'BAR';
$data = [
  'title' => $videoTitle,
  'description' => $videoDescription,
  'scheduled_publish_time' => strtotime('+7 days'),
  'published' => false,
];

$basePath = '/path/to/';
$fileEntry='file.mp4';
$response = $fb->uploadVideo('{PAGEID}', $basePath.$fileEntry, $data, $accessToken);
```

> `scheduled_publish_time` Time when this post should go live, this can be any date between ten minutes and six months from the time of the API call.

Possible formats for `scheduled_publish_time`:

- An integer UNIX timestamp [in seconds] (e.g. 1530432000).
- An ISO 8061 timestamp string (e.g. 2018-09-01T10:15:30+01:00).
- Any string otherwise parsable by PHP's strtotime() (e.g. +2 weeks, tomorrow).

For dates I'm not entirely sure which timezone should be used so maybe will require a bit of experiment.

Links:

- [Video Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/#Creating)
- [Page Video Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos/#parameters-2)
- [User Video Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/#parameters-2)
- Not video specific but a similar example of [Scheduling Posts for Pages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/common-scenarios#scheduledposts) and [another one here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing/?translation#schedule-a-page-post)

Comment: Just a minor correction, scheduled_publish_time, as of the current version of the API, accepts only integer UNIX timestamp.