# How to upload a video to Facebook as "Premiere"

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64455833/1543677) describes how to upload a video to Facebook as a scheduled video.

I am now looking how to publish a video as a "[Premiere](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/580544922399103?id=214359809769375)".

Differences between live, scheduled video, and premieres:

- A live video is being broadcast via RTMP, concurrently.
- A scheduled video is pre-uploaded in its entirety. After the
  scheduled time, the user can skip to any point in the video.
- A "premiere" is pre-uploaded in its entirety. After the scheduled
  time, Facebook simulates a broadcast. The user cannot skip ahead.

What's the proper parameter to set up the video as "Premiere"?

Comment: Are you sure this is even possible? [This article](https://www.facebook.com/business/learn/lessons/premiere-videos-from-creator-studio) talks quite strictly about eligibility. It also mentions _The only opportunity to set up a Premiere is when you first upload your video_, and gives step-by-step user instructions, but makes no mention of an API. I don't know how well-coordinated these user documentations are with developer docs. But it sounds a little like this is something they don't like to have automated.